# How to catch any end of a drag event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-events

Problem: having an element that set as `draggable`. Need to catch all cases when user finished to drag the element to attach a function to it. So far I use `mouseleave` and `mouseup` but still miss some cases.
Here is the code:

```
handleMaxEl
    .css('left', scope.max * rangeEl.width() / valuesNumber)
    .draggable({
        containment: '.range-holder',
        axis: 'x'
    })
    .on('drag', handlesHandler)
    .on('mouseup mounseleave', positionHandles);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      start: function() {
        counts[ 0 ]++;
        updateCounterStatus( $start_counter, counts[ 0 ] );
      },
      drag: function() {
        counts[ 1 ]++;
        updateCounterStatus( $drag_counter, counts[ 1 ] );
      },
      stop: function() {
        counts[ 2 ]++;
        updateCounterStatus( $stop_counter, counts[ 2 ] );
      }
    });
```

there are events for drag , start and stop http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stop` callback of **draggable** ,And is Triggered when dragging stops.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
stop: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

See more [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop).